# Keep Modal View row checkmarked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, modal-dialog

I have a RSS parser that displays the articles in a UITableView. I also have a button that brings up a Modal View where you can change the source of the RSS feed. I have 2 questions:

1. How do I keep the selected feed row checkmarked after I quit the app and open it again?
2. How do I call for the article table to reload when the modal view is dismissed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You need to persist your state and restore it programatically on re-launch.  You will likely want to store you state variables in NSUserDefaults.

2) Define a protocol for your modal view and have the view that presents that modal conform to it and act as the delegate.  You can then call your reload method when the modal view informs the delegate.  See this answer to the same question that came through just a bit ago: [Call method from Modal View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675866/call-method-from-modal-view-controller/1675933#1675933)